# What are the FFI extensions?

Tags: c++, scripting, ffi

I'm coding something in C++ and I would like to offer a scripting layer within my application, during a search for a workable solution I found this `FFI extensions` but I can't really find proper documentation for them, the guy who invented this or any other "reliable" and technical source, the only things that is clear to me is that this technology is cross-language, in LuaJit, Ruby and Haskell there is someone talking about this stuff but I have no clue about what this "thing" is.

Is something comparable to [SWIG](http://swig.org/) ? It's the new kid on the block ?

Comment: It's a way to call code from one language in another.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum pretty vague ... it's a feature from the compiler ? it's a runtime feature ? it's from what ? How it works ?

Comment: http://sourceware.org/libffi/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) is a concept. It's what many languages call their glue layer that enables you to call into other languages (very often this bridge is a to a C ABI), and it's thus different for each project. (e.g. [this](http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0007.html) for Erlang

[libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) is often used to implement that glue layer in the language, as is [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).

Comment: ok, it's ABI, so it's something that happens at runtime more or less, so where is the price that I pay and where are the pros ?

Comment: @user2485710 If you want to concretely use libffi, you're best off reading its documentation. If you want to invent your own FFI, you're in charge. The pros are quite simple, A) You can call stuff written in another language.

Comment: Its not from compiler nor "the runtime". Cross-language tools are usually just libraries that must be used properly at both sides to get the effect. You've got TWO+ languages, two+ runtimes, and ~two compilers. When speaking about i.e. C++ and Ruby, most of the time the C++ will be the lower and Ruby will be the upper level one. The lower one will need you to add extra metainformation into the module at compile time, while the upper one will read those and use them at runtime. So, the cost is at both sides. Your C++ code will get 'dirtier', and the scripting environment will get 'heavier'.

Comment: To the downvoter: it'd be nice to know why you're downvoting a perfectly proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for a very generic answer, but your questio also seems such..

In contrast to Java, there is no "one FFI" and there's no "one reliable scripting environment". In Java you have the JS Rhino scripting language almost 'built in' into the JRE.

C/C++ have the power of "relatively easily" interfacing with all/any of other platforms. This is because all other platforms are usually implemented in C/C++. Sorry for generalizing and oversimplifying. But, the point is, that IF you had the other-platforms' C++ sourcecodes, you'd add new things to them, just by observing how the standard ones were created.

The point is, that usually all other platforms are either:

- closed source
- open source, but licensed in a way that prevents you from using it
- open source, well-licensed, but LARGE/COMPLICATED enough, that you simply dont want to compile/change their internals

Therefore, every other platform produces on its own some way of calling C APIs. It's just so that i.e. you can use Win32API from Ruby/Python without really recompiling whole Python's runtime just because you wanted to call `SendKeys` etc.

So, usually, it's the "other platforms" that call into C/C++ than the other way. It's because they all already **have a way** to do that. Even Java has JNI and .net has P/Invoke, right?

But, now, the calling C++-from-X is possible, depending on X or Y or Z platform, it differs very much. And very often, it works but is tedious to define or just unwieldy. I.e. in Ruby on Windows you can call any C api by:

- giving the actual name of the function i.e. `_@@2AV21moveMeByDistance`
- giving encoded list of parameter types i.e. `ifpp` (int,float,pointer,pointer)
- giving the proper parameters in proper types and order

if you don't follow, it will crash badly. The above examples are artificial an incorrect by the way. But it looks similar.

So, on almost any platform, there have been many tools to simplify that. On all platforms - different ones. But all are called FFI - line **nos** said, because it is a concept.

The tools may i.e. require you to annotate the C++ code with some extra information like:

```
 class RUBIZE MyClass :: BaseThing
 {
     PUBLIC(void,int,int) void moveMeByDistance(int x, int y) { ... }
     PUBLIC(void)         void .......
 };
```

and then they can process your .h files to generate the "bindings" automatically and they then generate a "binding library" that will adjust the scripting environment so that you can now directly call `MyClass::moveMyByDistance(5,6)` from script.

Or, they can require you to **register** all the bits at runtime, ie.:

```
 class MyClass :: ScriptObject
 {
     void moveMeByDistance(int x, int y) { ... }
     void .......
 };

 int dllmain()
 {
     ScriptingEnv::RegisterClass<MyClass>();
     ScriptingEnv::RegisterClass( "move", &MyClass::moveMeByDistance );
     ScriptingEnv::RegisterClass( "eat", .... );
 }
```

but again, all of the above examples are artificial.

As the C/C++ can interface to any other platform (thanks to the fact that any other platform usually has tools for that :P), you have to **first decide** which scripting language you would like to use. JS? Lua? Ruby? Python? All of them can. Then look for libraries that provide you with the most comfy way of bridging. There are many, but you will have to look at sites/forums/etc related to that very language. Or even here, but then ask about concrete languge/library.

Keywords to look for are:

- modules  --- i.e. "extending XYZ Script with new modules"
- extensions  --- i.e. "writing extensions for Ruby in C++"
- bindings    --- i.e. "Ruby bindings for FastFourierTransform Library"
- calling C/C++ code/classes from XYZ languge

etc.

Comment: so this FFI heavily relies on the calling convention of both C and C++ ?  I also assume that SWIG is safer than FFI at runtime.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the basic problem completely. You still do not understand what FFI is. There is no such thing as **that FFI**. "FFI" is general term/name for a class of tools. FFI is as abstract as the word "language" that describes C#, Java, C++, Lisp, and others. Look at SWIG: it requires you to keep extra files with interface definitions along with your C++ code. SWIG is an FFI utility: it is a processor that reads files and generates bindings/code for other langs, prepared so that **calling/using** the **foreign-language-functions** is easily done on both sides.

Comment: Please take some time and read the article that **nos** pointed out. Yes, it's WIKI article for FFI. Read it and pay attention at `In addition, many FFIs can` line just before 'see also' footer. Precisely mentions SWIG.

Comment: But SWIG is just one toolset/library that is capable of providing such thing. It is very good because it handles many languages. However, if you don't care about "many", and want to work with one specific i.e. "Ruby", there are tons of other tools, specializing in that or other language. All called something-near "FFI"/"extensions"/"bindings"..